# Rails select, keep value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

this is probably embarrassing to ask and pretty simple. What I wanna do is, when I'm editing my profile, I want my selector to keep its value which I choose at the first time. For example:

Status: Single, In a relationship, Engaged, Married.

If I choose In a relationship and I want to edit that, the value is still there and not in the order "Single, In a relationship and so on..." Here's my code:

```
<%= c.select(:relationship_status, options_for_select([["Singel", :singel], ["I ett förhållande", :förhållande], ["Förlovad", :förlovad], ["Gift", :gift]], {:prompt => true, :selected => !!params[:relationship_status]})) %>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly this is a question about ordering the attribute options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
c.select(:relationship_status, options_for_select([["Singel", :singel], ["I ett förhållande", :förhållande], ["Förlovad", :förlovad], ["Gift", :gift]], params[:relationship_status]), prompt: true)
```

If you look at the documentation for [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) it has the following example:

```
options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard" ], "MasterCard")

<option>VISA</option>
<option selected="selected">MasterCard</option>
```

Comment: It didn't solve my request... Let us say that I register my account and I choose a town where I live, I suddenly move somewhere and I want to change town in "edit profile", what I want is that my town where I live in is still selected. For example: Town, 1, Town, 2, Town, 3, and I live in town, 3 and when I'm editing the profile, the selected value "town 3" is still there.

Comment: Ah I see, ok let's say the object for the form is `@details`, then try changing the `params[:relationship_status]` to `@details.relationship_status`. That should return `nil` if the object is new, or a value if it has already been created.